# Mandatory Merged Cell Input for excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I had a merged cell from D4 to H4, I want the cells to be mandatory. I had tried the following code but does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set c = Range("D4:H4")

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, c) Is Nothing Then
  For Each cel In c
    If cel.Text = "" Then
      Application.Goto reference:=c, Scroll:=True
      MsgBox ("Field Cannot Be Blank")
      Exit For
    End If
  Next cel
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I also had another cell need to be mandatory, H2. This code already works, I want to combine the codes for D4 to H4 and H2 together.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(2, 8).Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cell H2 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the 
  mandatory cells"
  Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If the cell is already merged, just work against `D4` - that's the only one that will return the value of the entire merged cell. Looping over the merged addresses is not going to work.
Other than that consider redesigning the worksheet. Merged cells are satan.

Comment: I tried using the code that words for single cell, and I did the what you mention, but it does not work.

Comment: You have to remove the single space between your quotation marks. Otherwise you do not check for an empty cell but for a string containing one space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out, but after removing the space, it also did not work, there's no error being pop out. I already edit my question to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Rik Sportel, I tried to remerged the cells and apply elseif statement and it works now.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(4, 4).Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cell D4 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
  Cancel = True
ElseIf Cells(2, 8).Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cell H2 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
  Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome. The solution in the question actually worked (except for the loop, hence my comment), but would only trigger at the moment the user does select the merged cell: `Target` in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event handler refers to the newly selected cell, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel). Therefore `If Not Intersect(Target, c) Is Nothing` will only be true when you click the merged cell. The validation message was displayed only then and only when the cell was empty.